# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed When I Try To Post a Form Into Database

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to post a form into mysql database. I'm using windows 8 and iis 8 but when i try to  post the form i get this error *"The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used."*

My html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>odev3</title>
</head>
<body>
<form align="middle" action="insert.php" method="post">
Ad : <input type="text" name="ad" style="margin-left:60px" required/><br>
Soyad : <input type="text" name="soyad" style="margin-left:40px" required/><br>
Kullanıcı Adı : <input type="text" name="kullaniciadi" required/><br>
Şifre : <input type="text" name="sifre" style="margin-left:52px" required/><br>
<input type="reset" value="Temizle"/>
<input type="submit" value="Kaydol"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my php code:

```
 <?php 
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="123";

    mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

    mysql_select_db("odev3"); 

    $sql="INSERT INTO kisi(ad,soyad,kullaniciadi,sifre) VALUES ('$_POST[ad]','$_POST[soyad]','$_POST[kullaniciadi]','$_POST[sifre]')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result)
    {
      echo("<br> Veri eklendi.");
    }
    else
    {
      echo("<br> Veri eklenemedi.");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does it say when you post it? then what is the URL you are getting? post the error url here

Comment: Yes, first i see the form and i fill it. When i click the submit button then i get the error and this url: http://localhost:19853/insert.php

Answer (score 1):

Is your server IIS? And what is the version?

This can be many problems, but the most common is your IIS is not configured to handle PHP files of type or IIS do not know the verb POST. Sometimes just use GET will work, but is better try to fix your IIS.

Please look at these links:

- http://www.somacon.com/p126.php
- http://dotnetstock.com/technical/http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed-invalid-method-http-verb-when-posting-a-form-in-asp-net